# Is there a way to read and write file to local storage system by calling aws lambda function in python

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a python function which writes to an audio file. I want to get the file to my local system as soon as I trigger AWS Lambda. I don't want to use S3 Bucket for this.
I have checked the method to store the file in /tmp/ folder in aws. But I don't know how to get the file to my local file system.
If there is any other way please let me know. Or how to get audio file from lambda /tmp/ folder to my local machine.

I have successfully written to /tmp/ folder it works fine.

```py
with('/tmp/filename.wav', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(content)
```

As soon as I trigger lambda function from API Gateway I want 'wav' file on my local machine.

Comment: There is [DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/index.html), but there's a lot to set up - it's almost certainly overkill. To build your own, though, you'd need something running on your local machine at all times, securely accessible from the internet so that your lambda on AWS can send things to it. S3 is the easiest way to achieve this by a million miles.

Comment: Is there a way where I can send file as response when the lambda function is triggered.

Comment: No. The lambda doesn't know anything about your local machine. Your machine might be turned off when the lambda is triggered, or you might have several machines. Even if it did know where to send things, you'd need something running on your machine to receive the file. The lambda is totally asynchronous.

Comment: What you *can* do is put the file somewhere so you can come and get it. That could be an SNS queue or something, but the most common place to put things like this is S3. I don't understand why you don't want to use it.

Comment: You could run a simple, publicly available  sftp server and have lambda push the file to your machine via sftp. - you  could use ngrok to get around any firewall issues and make your sftp server publicly available even if you can't have a public incoming port open for this.

Comment: I want the file to be downloaded on the machine which calls that api. Also I can store the file on tmp folder in AWS Lambda, but I don't know how to get the file from there.

Comment: using sftp, you'd send the DNS address of your local machine to your lambda function when you initiate it, and your lambda program would act as a ftp client, log onto your local machine, and push the file there. - the file can't be "downloaded" because lambda is asynchronous.  It knows nothing about the connection that caused it to run. It has to "upload" the file to you on its own as an independent connection that it initiates.

Comment: You'd need a static public IP address for your local machine, or course, and you have all the reliability issues to deal with and so on. If you're going for an AWS lambda, it usually precisely to avoid all the shenanigans. I still need to know what the OP is avoiding S3 and SNS, since they are the clear winners in terms of simplicity.

Comment: So I could just write audio file to S3 and get the file to the machine that is calling that api.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you want to save the file to your local as soon as the Lambda is invoked, but I think what you mean is that as son as your Lambda is done whatever is doing you want to save the resultant file to your Local machine.

If I’m correct about the above, then subject to the limits of Lambda and API gateway you can return the audio file as the result of the function; in your function, simply have it return the resulting file in the response.

As per the AWS documentation, the maximum payload size from API gateway is 10MB, and API gateway has a timeout of 30 seconds ([see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html)). That being said, the maximum invocation payload of Lambda is 6MB ([see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)). These two combined means that your response from Lambda has to be less than 6MB and complete within 30 seconds. If the response is more than 6MB or takes more than 30 seconds, then you will receive an error.

Although you mentioned that you don’t wish to use S3, a better pattern, especially if your file size could be larger than 6MB, would be to use S3 to store the file, and have Lambda/API gateway return a “302 Found” redirect with the location of the file in S3; your browser will still automatically download it to your local machine, but you won’t have to worry about API gateway timeouts, or Lambda response limits.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility would be for your lambda write your output to Dropbox using the [Dropbox api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python). Dropbox is very good at keeping files synced to local machines.

You'll need to be careful with your keys - I suggest [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) for this, which you can [get to easily from Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-python-example_code-secretsmanager.html).